# Can I get missing achievements by replaying missions from the archive?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I had some internet connection problems so I have decided to complete some missions offline and I was not credited achievements for these missions. If I want to get these achievements, is going to the archive and completing these certain missions again enough? Or do I have to start the campaign from scratch?

For example, I was not credited an achievement for doing the baneling evolution mission and I really need it for the portrait. I clicked on the Void Seeker which is also needed for a portrait but it shows that I did not click on it.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the achievements by replaying the missions from the archive. Don't restart the campaign because, assuming it works the same way as it did in Wings of Liberty, that will kill your ability to use the full mission archive until you complete it again.

And, of course, make sure you stay connected to Battle.net while replaying the missions.

As [Raven Dreamer reminded me](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113061/can-i-get-missing-achievements-by-replaying-missions-from-the-archive/113065#comment151526_113065), anything that requires actions done in-between campaign missions would require restarting the campaign. So, to get the Void Seeker click, you'll have to replay from the beginning up to the point where that's available in the campaign.

Comment: Also worth noting that there are Master Archives - accessible from main menu after completing the storyline. While replaying missions from there, you are able to choose any evolution, mutation and Kerrigan power, and the game assumes you do the mission as late as possible (i.e. in the Baneling mission you'd have evolved Hydra, evolved Roaches, Muta and Swarm Hosts).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Maybe I will only need to complete the mission before the appearence of the Void Seeker not the whole campaign, I'll try it today and see how it goes.

Comment: Note that the Level 70 Kerrigan Achievement has to be done in one play-through as well. I had to restart the campaign, just playing the missions missing a level did not help with this.

Comment: @AntonRoth Good to know. You can definitely miss levels and go back  to the archives to get them before you finish the last mission though.

Comment: @Anton, this has been fixed. If I'm not mistaken, blizzard patched that recently. I finished the campaign with a 69 Kerrigan and just replayed the mission later that missed the level up.